# Upgrading AKS to the latest stable version via python begin_create_or_update()

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-aks

I have used the following python code in order to upgrade AKS to the latest version. However I am wondering if the latest version here is the stable version?

I couldn't find some info regarding this in docz.
If we used auto-upgrade-channel it has an option to specify "stable", how would that work with this method that I used?

```
for resource in list(resource_list):
    if resource.type== "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters":
       location=resource.location
       print("Location:", location)
       containerservice_client = ContainerServiceClient(credential, sub.subscription_id)
       get_aks = containerservice_client.managed_clusters.get(group.name, resource.name)
                    
       print("Getting availabele versions on AKS Cluster....")
       aks_get_version = containerservice_client.managed_clusters.get_upgrade_profile(group.name, resource.name)
  
       aks_get_upgrade = aks_get_version.control_plane_profile
       upgrades = aks_get_upgrade.upgrades
       print("ResourceName:", resource.name, "AKS_current_Version", aks_get_upgrade.kubernetes_version)
       current_version = aks_get_upgrade.kubernetes_version
       agent_pool=containerservice_client.agent_pools.list(group.name, resource.name)
       if upgrades:
          for i in upgrades:
              print("ResourceName:", resource.name, "AKSAvailable_Versions_List:", i.kubernetes_version,i.is_preview)
              latest_version = i.kubernetes_version
          print("Latest Available Version:", latest_version)      
          for x in agent_pool:
              agent_pool_name=x.name
              print("Agent_Pool_Name:",x.name)
          if latest_version != current_version:
             print("Upgrading to a new version....")
             param=ManagedCluster(location=location, kubernetes_version=latest_version,agent_pool_profiles=[ManagedClusterAgentPoolProfile(orchestrator_version=latest_version,name=agent_pool_name,mode=x.mode,type=x.type_properties_type)])
                        update_aks=containerservice_client.managed_clusters.begin_create_or_update(resource_group_name=group.name,resource_name=resource.name,parameters=param)     
          else:
            print("Kubernetes version is the latest one!")    
       else:
          print("There is no new updates available!")
```

I would appreciate if someone can explain it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Microsoft Documentation , stable feature which is offered by auto-upgrade channel is as below :

[image]

And also adding to that the auto-upgrade feature only upgrades to GA versions and not Preview versions.

So ,I have modified the code as per the requirement and it will be something like below:

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient
from azure.mgmt.containerservice.models import (ManagedClusterAgentPoolProfile,
                                                ManagedCluster)

credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "mysub"
resource_group= 'myresourcegroup'
resouce_client=ResourceManagementClient(credential,subscription_id)
containerservice_client=ContainerServiceClient(credential,subscription_id)
resource_list=resouce_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(resource_group)
for resource in list(resource_list):
if resource.type == "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters":
   location=resource.location
   print("Location:", location)
   get_aks = containerservice_client.managed_clusters.get(resource_group, resource.name)          
   print("Getting availabele versions on AKS Cluster....")
   aks_get_version = containerservice_client.managed_clusters.get_upgrade_profile(resource_group, resource.name)

   aks_get_upgrade = aks_get_version.control_plane_profile
   upgrades = aks_get_upgrade.upgrades
   print("ResourceName:", resource.name, "AKS_current_Version", aks_get_upgrade.kubernetes_version)
   current_version = aks_get_upgrade.kubernetes_version
   agent_pool=containerservice_client.agent_pools.list(resource_group, resource.name)
   if upgrades:
      latest_version=list()
      preview=list()
      l= (len(upgrades)-1)
      print(l)
      for i in upgrades:
          print("ResourceName:", resource.name, "AKSAvailable_Versions_List:", i.kubernetes_version, "Preview:" , i.is_preview)
          latest_version.append(i.kubernetes_version)
          preview.append(i.is_preview)
      latest_stable_version = latest_version[-l]
      version_preview_for_stable=preview[-l]
      print("Latest Stable Available Version:", latest_stable_version)
      for x in agent_pool:
        agent_pool_name=x.name
        print("Agent_Pool_Name:",x.name)
      if version_preview_for_stable == None and latest_stable_version != current_version :
        print("Upgrading to a new version....")

      else:
        print("Kubernetes version is the latest one!")    
   else:
      print("There is no new updates available!")
```

**Output : **

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I'm just wondering why you check this part? "if version_preview_for_stable == None"

Comment: @Matrix, as i don't want preview versions and the auto-upgrade feature also doesn't upgrade to preview features I added the `version_preview_for_stable == None"` for the stable version to be upgraded to

Comment: I see. Thanks. Then in parameter part you used latest_stable_version, right? param=ManagedCluster(location=location, kubernetes_version=latest_stable_version,agent_pool_profiles=[ManagedClusterAgentPoolProfile(orchestrator_version=latest_stable_version,name=agent_pool_name,mode=x.mode,type=x.type_properties_type)])

Comment: yes @Matrix, you are correct.

Comment: I just tested it and got en error regarding list: Exception: IndexError: list index out of range. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239977/discussion-between-ansumanbal-mt-and-matrix).

Comment: Based on our chat, changing latest_stable_version = latest_version[l] to latest_stable_version = latest_version[-1] worked fine. Thanks :)

Comment: @Matrix, glad to be of help :)